# Nomenclature of C6H5CO-O-NH2

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, aromatic-compounds, carbonyl-compounds, amines

How to name the following compound using IUPAC nomenclature? I found [benzyl carbamate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benzyl_carbamate) to be very close to my structure, but couldn't find an exact compound online which matches mine.

[image: CAS 54495‐98‐6]

Comment: @Maurice Why exactly do you think there would be no O-benzoil derivative of hydroxylamine?

Comment: Let's say it does exist, but is so unlikely that we are compelled to suspect a mistake.

Comment: im new to organic chemistry. @IvanNeretin why is it so unlikely?

Comment: Because of the bond between O and N.

Comment: Sort of cheating, but the CAS number for your compound is 54495‐98‐6 (added as image metadata) so you can learn more about the molecule. [ChemSpider](https://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.166153.html?rid=1a6684ab-0059-4c40-8262-d500459f7cd9) might be a good start.

Comment: @IvanNeretin  Not only is it a known compound, it is commercially available - as O-benzoylhydroxylamine   https://www.biosynth.com/p/ECA49598/54495-98-6-o-benzoyl-hydroxylamine-hydrochloride

Answer (score 7):

According to the last printed version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001)*, the retained name **hydroxylamine** was used for the construction of the preferred name.

> **P-68.3.1.1.1** Hydroxylamines
>
> The retained name ‘hydroxylamine’ is a preselected name and designates the structure $\ce{H2N-OH}$. It is a functional parent compound allowing full substitution even, as an exception, on the oxygen atom. (…)

> **P-68.3.1.1.1.2** Substitution on the oxygen atom of hydroxylamine
>
> Substitution of hydroxylamine on the oxygen atom by hydrocarbyl or acyl groups is
> expressed as *O*-substitution. (…)

> $\ce{H2N-O-CO-C6H5}$
> *O*-benzoylhydroxylamine (PIN)

However, this was changed on 3 March 2021. The PIN is now given as **aminooxy(phenyl)methanone.**

(I am not sure if this still contains a mistake and should actually read (aminooxy)(phenyl)methanone.)

Comment: but isnt this some sort of ester? i dont understand

Comment: Here it should be some sort of benzoate right? something like aminomethyl benzoate?

Comment: @kzmom Hmm, but hydroxylamine is not an alcohol, so it cannot be an ester, AFAIK.

Comment: @kzmom One could in principle call it azanyl benzoate, but it's rather an amide analogue made with hydroxylamine instead of ammonia. Something like one tried to make peroxyacid amide.

Comment: hmmm my teacher says it is peroxo benzamide

Comment: @kzmom Peroxo implies *two* oxygen atoms - I already mentioned this analogy, but it's useless in nomenclature. Only group of compounds this belongs is  O-acylhydroxylamines.